# Exotic filetypes not loading after build in react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, mp3, webp

i created a `create-react-app` and want to use filetypes like `webp` or `mp3`.
When i run my application on localhost via `npm run start` everything works fine, but after my deployment on my server (which uses `npm run build` and delivers the build folder) it doesn't load filetypes like `mp3` or `webp` anymore. Why is this happening? i think its any simple configuration in react or anything like that, but i cant solve this problem by my own. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with typescript (if that is what you're using). Typescript will convert `.ts` and `.tsx` files to `.js`, but not move most other files over to `build`.  If they are in a separate `assets` directory, you have to ensure that gets deployed too. If this is the issue, you have a few choices.

You can manually move the files over to `build` as a 'post' deploy step (using say, a shell script).
You can use a bundler like `webpack` to help you maintain the references to those other assets and bundle them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found out it was a webserver caused problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem that caused this behaviour. Amazon AWS Amplify creates a rewrite rule for single page applications (SPA). You can find this setting under `Rewrites and redirects` in your Amplify application settings. There you will find a rewrite rule with following source address:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

...change it to...

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|mp3)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

... for example, to allow mp3 files. This is also important to allow webp-Images or woff2-Fonts.